# How to commit new changes to an open merge request?

Tags: gitlab, push, branch, commit, merge-request

I am new to working in branching and git.

I developed some test cases and created new branch to push the changes in that branch and opened a merge request in GitLab to be merged in master branch.

After PR, my reviewer highlighted some code refactoring and other minor changes.

Now, I have made those changes and the merge request is still open.  How can I push the new changes/commit to an already opened merge request?

Comment: Just push the commits to the same branch.

Comment: So, I should follow these steps? -> git add . -> git commit --amend --no-edit -> git push

Comment: Hamza, yes, new commits are automatically added to open MR

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, I should follow these steps? -> git add . -> git commit --amend --no-edit -> git push

No need for `git commit --amend`: you can make a new commit, explaining why those changes are introduced, and push.

That will update the current MR (Merge Request in GitLab parlor).

As mentioned in "[Merge requests versions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/versions.html)"/

> Every time you push to a branch that is tied to a merge request, a new version of merge request diff is created.
>
> When you visit a merge request that contains more than one pushes, you can select and compare the versions of those merge request diffs.